# How to read a Java heap dump by command line (No GUI)

Tags: java, heap-dump

I've ssh'ed into a machine and am running a java program. After quit a while, I get a heap dump and have sent that into a file java_pid28356.hprof How can I read from that file with just command line tools to find what is causing the dump?

Answer (score 1):

```
less %DUMP_FILE_DIR%/java_pid28356.hprof
```

Also you can try ParseHeapDump.sh - part of eclipse memory analyzer (you can google it, but I post the script below for your convenience)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script parses a heap dump.
# Adjust the path to java, version 5 or later, and the heap size as required.
# Suitable for 64-bit and 32-bit Java, but a 64-bit Java is required
# for larger heap sizes.
#
# Usage: ParseHeapDump.sh <path/to/dump.dmp.zip> [report]*
#
# The leak report has the id org.eclipse.mat.api:suspects
# The top component report has the id org.eclipse.mat.api:top_components
#

java -Xmx3072M -jar "`dirname "$0"`"/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1*.jar -consoleLog -application org.eclipse.mat.api.parse "$@"
```

Comment: I already tried tools like less that just output the file but it is a binary. Here is an excerpt of what it prints out.

@^@^@^@^Z^@^@^?_x^E<CD><C0>unsignedEntryNames^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@        ^@^@^?_|F<9D>P/^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@^?_|Hh<80>0^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ESC^@^@^?_|F<DC>^@java/io/InputStream^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@%^@^@^?_x^M<DD>pIllegal octal escape sequence^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@.^@^@^?_|J^WPjava/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom
^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@    ^@^@^?_|G<C4>`:^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@^?_|G<FF><F0>;^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@      ^@^@^?_|Gz0<^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^U^@^@^?_|FESC`getAndAddLong^A^@^@^@^@

Comment: what did you expect? if you know what to look for it should be enough. You can try the 2nd option I suggested if you feel lucky.

Comment: I was hoping for something like the GUIs make. Something like the percentage of the heap that is made of Strings, ints, etc.